# Environment variable not being set in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project with 2 Dockerfiles, one for backend and one for database. The dockerfiles are in separate folders. I build the two images with a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  dotnet-backend:
    container_name: dotnet-backend
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    links:
      - mssql-db
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  mssql-db:
    container_name: mssql-db
    build: ./Database
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
     - ./Database/:/scripts/
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    expose:
      - "1433"
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
        sleep infinity
```

As you can see, I use a .env file for environment variables, this file is located in the src folder, same as the Dockerfile for the backend and the rest of the backend code.

This is my Dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o out MyProject.csproj

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

This is my Dockerfile for the database (located in ./Database):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=$SA_PASSWORD
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433 

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./ /scripts/

EXPOSE 1433 

RUN (/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && sleep 5s && (for foo in /scripts/*.sql;do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -P$SA_PASSWORD  -i$foo;done)
```

And finally my .env file:

```
SA_PASSWORD=SomePassword
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ConnectionStrings__My_db=Data Source=tcp:mssql-db,1433;Initial Catalog=DevDB;User ID=sa;Password=SomePassword
```

What's strange is that the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable gets set, as I can tell by testing my API that it is running in development mode, and the connection string from the .env file also gets set as my API can connect to my database when I manually enter the password. But the SA_PASSWORD environment variable does not get set. Here is the output from the docker-compose up --build command:

[image]

So why are the other variables and connection strings getting set, but not the password? Everything works fine if I replace `ENV SA_PASSWORD=$SA_PASSWORD` with `ENV SA_PASSWORD=SomePassword` in the database Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to set the env vars in the docker images at all, and you can fix the issue using the changes below

**ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** works because the app only check it at runtime and not at build time

database docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433

WORKDIR /src
COPY ./ /scripts/

EXPOSE 1433 

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh (chmod a+x)

```
#!/bin/bash -e


(/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && sleep 5s && (for foo in /scripts/*.sql;do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -P$SA_PASSWORD  -i$foo;done)

exec "$@"

exit 0
```

app docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o out MyProject.csproj

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

you can move also these to the env file and it is recommended to separate the env files for the containers

```
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
```

Comment: So I tried this and both containers build just fine, but when docker tries to run the database container it returns "standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"". I placed the docker-entrypoint.sh script in the database folder together with the Dockerfile and .env for the database. I'm running on Windows if it matters.

Comment: it seems that the ```exec "$@"``` failed to execute the command from the docker container. Try to move the command to the entry point and remove  ```exec "$@"```

Comment: After doing some research it seems that the image and my system have different architectures which causes the script to not be able to run (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4558), but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I got it working now, it was the formatting of the shell script that was wrong. However, now I get this error: `Sqlcmd: '/scripts/*.sql': Invalid filename.` which indicates that there is something wrong with the copying of the scripts when the image is built

Comment: change it to ```for x in `ls /scripts/*.sql` ```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a valid way to take a var from environment.

The variable $SA_PASSWORD in Dockerfile is actually a var into scope of Dockerfile and build image time.

The var hasn't value because the way of assign it, is through ARG command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).

Everyway, if you need declare a SA_PASSWORD and read it of environment at container runtime, you must do it trough ENTRYPOINT. ENTRYPOINT is executed when container launch.

Comment: But how come my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT works then? It is set exactly the same way.

Comment: The entrypoint for that image is the binary "dotnet", in docker case variable could be setted at build time trough ARG or ENVIRONMENT. On other hand, the "dotnet" is the entrypoint when it run check the environemnt variable and allow you to change at launch time.

Comment: I mean is managed by dotnet, is not the same case that your own var. Btw, mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server image seems to already has SA_PASSWORD in consideration. https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server Did you try delete that line and just use it?